# Don't Delete Oldest Files In Directory ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement to delete all files in a directory, except for the 5 that were created the longest time ago. So if I have a directory with files that were created on.

11/6/2010, 11/5/2010, 11/4/2010, 11/3/2010, 11/2/2010, 11/1/2010

The only file to be deleted would be the one created on 11/6/2010. What is the best way to do this in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A link to get started: [Sorting Directory.GetFiles()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles)

Comment: Agreed. This thing called LINQ might just be the greatest thing to arrive in programming. Ever.