# Getting files by creation date in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have a folder which contains many files. Is there any easy way to get the file names in the directory sorted by their creation date/time?

If I use `Directory.GetFiles()`, it returns the files sorted by their file name.

Comment: I found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles

Comment: GetFiles() does *not* sort, getting them ordered by name is an accident.  Just sort yourself.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

this could work for you.

```
using System.Linq;

DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("PATH_TO_DIRECTORY_HERE");
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    // DO Something...
}
```

Comment: 'System.IO.FileInfo[]' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy'

Comment: It's an extension method... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Comment: I think there's no need to call the ToArray() method.

Comment: AnyIdeas without using extension methods/LINQ because I'm targeting .NET 2.0

Comment: Consider using info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTimeUtc) instead of CreationTime if there's any chance the files in the directory may have been created in different time zones (including daylight savings time)

Answer (score 61):

You can use Linq

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\", "*").OrderByDescending(d => new FileInfo(d).CreationTime);
```

Comment: The DirectoryInfo solution is much faster then this (especially for network path)

Comment: thank you @jing, for me the DirectoryInfo method takes about 0.5 seconds and this methods about 50 seconds and it's only 16000 files ^^

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to use LINQ

```
// Get the files
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("path/to/files"));
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles();

// Sort by creation-time descending 
Array.Sort(files, delegate(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2)
{
    return f2.CreationTime.CompareTo(f1.CreationTime);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

This returns the last modified date and its age.

```
DateTime.Now.Subtract(System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(FilePathwithName).Date)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the performance is an issue, you can use this command in MS_DOS:

```
dir /OD >d:\dir.txt
```

This command generate a **dir.txt** file in **d:** root the have all files sorted by date.
And then read the file from your code.
Also, you add other filters  by * and ?.

Answer (score 1):

@jing: "The DirectoryInfo solution is much faster then this (especially for network path)"

I cant confirm this.
It seems as if Directory.GetFiles triggers a filesystem or network cache.
The first request takes a while, but the following requests are much faster, even if new files were added.
In my test I did a Directory.getfiles and a info.GetFiles with the same patterns and both run equally

```
GetFiles  done 437834 in00:00:20.4812480
process files  done 437834 in00:00:00.9300573
GetFiles by Dirinfo(2)  done 437834 in00:00:20.7412646
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            DirectoryInfo dirinfo = new DirectoryInfo(strMainPath);
            String[] exts = new string[] { "*.jpeg", "*.jpg", "*.gif", "*.tiff", "*.bmp","*.png", "*.JPEG", "*.JPG", "*.GIF", "*.TIFF", "*.BMP","*.PNG" };
            ArrayList files = new ArrayList();
            foreach (string ext in exts)
                files.AddRange(dirinfo.GetFiles(ext).OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToArray());
```