# C# pick most recent file returning "most recent" based on title rather than write time

Tags: c#, datetime, file-io, ssis

I've taken the answer into account and added it to my code however for some reason even when to files have very different write times it seems to be taking the one with the higher digit in its name rather than the one with the most recent write time.

I previously posted this question but was unable to get an answer , now I've posted the full code I'm using as I'm stumped as to what the problem is , TO CLARIFY : My aim here is to sort through a directory and get certain files , some files may have the same name and so in this case I need to ensure that only the most recent file is taken , as far as I can see I have accounted for this in my code but it will not work .. Any help greatly appreciated

```
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\DevP\Custom");

    /// Returns latest writen file from the specified directory.
    /// If the directory does not exist or doesn't contain any file, DateTime.MinValue      is returned.
    /// <param name="directoryInfo">Path of the directory that needs to be  scanned</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static DateTime GetLatestWriteTimeFromFileInDirectory(DirectoryInfo  directoryInfo)
    {
        if (directoryInfo == null || !directoryInfo.Exists)
            return DateTime.MinValue;

        FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
        DateTime lastWrite = DateTime.MinValue;

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            if (file.LastWriteTime > lastWrite)
            {
                lastWrite = file.LastWriteTime;
            }
        }



        return lastWrite;
    }

    /// Returns latest writen timestamp file from the specified directory.
    /// If the directory does not exist or doesn't contain any file, DateTime.MinValue  is returned.

    private static FileInfo GetLatestWritenFileFileInDirectory(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {
        if (directoryInfo == null || !directoryInfo.Exists)
            return null;

        FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
        DateTime lastWrite = DateTime.MinValue;
        FileInfo lastWritenFile = null;

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            if (file.Name.StartsWith("GLA"))
            {
                if (file.LastWriteTime > lastWrite)
                {
                    lastWrite = file.LastWriteTime;
                    lastWritenFile = file;
                }
            }

            else if (file.Name.StartsWith("M&M"))
            {
                if (file.LastWriteTime > lastWrite)
                {
                    lastWrite = file.LastWriteTime;
                    lastWritenFile = file;
                }
            }

            else if (file.Name.StartsWith("TRIAL"))
            {
                if (file.LastWriteTime > lastWrite)
                {
                    lastWrite = file.LastWriteTime;
                    lastWritenFile = file;
                }

            }



        }
        return lastWritenFile;
```

}

```
    public void Main()
    {
        String keywordHorizon =  ((String)Dts.Variables["User::KeywordGLA"].Value).ToUpper();

        string filename = Dts.Variables["User::InputFile"].Value.ToString();
        string checkname = filename.ToUpper();



        if (Equals("CurrentProcess.arc", Dts.Variables["User::InputFile"].Value) ==  false)
        {
            String FullFilePath = filename;
            int filecounter = 0;  // Increment for counting files, if found



            FileInfo fileinfo;
            fileinfo = new FileInfo(FullFilePath);

            if (checkname.Contains(keywordeHorizon))
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::GLAFile"].Value = FullFilePath;
                filecounter = 1;
                if (fileinfo.Exists)
                {

                    if (fileinfo.Length == 0)
                    {
                        Dts.Variables["User::FileHasNoData"].Value = true;
                        Dts.Variables["User::PackageStatus"].Value = "ERROR";
                        Dts.Variables["User::Succeeded"].Value = false;
                    }
                    else
                        GetLatestWritenFileFileInDirectory(directoryInfo);

                }
            }
            else if (checkname.Contains(keywordM&M))
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::M&Mfile"].Value = FullFilePath;
                filecounter = 1;
                if (fileinfo.Exists)
                {
                    if (fileinfo.Length == 0)
                    {
                        Dts.Variables["User::FileHasNoData"].Value = true;
                        Dts.Variables["User::PackageStatus"].Value = "ERROR";
                        Dts.Variables["User::Succeeded"].Value = false;
                    }

                    else
                        GetLatestWritenFileFileInDirectory(directoryInfo);

                }

            }
            else if (checkname.Contains(keywordTRIAL))
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::TRIALFile"].Value = FullFilePath;
                filecounter = 1;
                if (fileinfo.Exists)
                {
                    if (fileinfo.Length == 0)
                    {
                        Dts.Variables["User::FileHasNoData"].Value = true;
                        Dts.Variables["User::PackageStatus"].Value = "ERROR";
                        Dts.Variables["User::Succeeded"].Value = false;
                    }

                    else
                        GetLatestWritenFileFileInDirectory(directoryInfo);

                }

            }
            Dts.Variables["User::FileCount"].Value =   (int)Dts.Variables["User::FileCount"].Value + filecounter;
        }



        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 'some files may have the same name', how? They have to vary at least by extension, so name won't by the same

Comment: in the current directory I have 4 files , two of them have the same name and this is causing the program not to work as it isn't pickinging the most recent and using that

Comment: @wudzik , I'm not sure , I asked that and was told that because of how they are being taken in they may have the same name

Comment: From the use of `StartsWith` I guess that "same name" means they start the same. Because as @wudzik points out, a filename must be unique (per directory).

Comment: @corak yeah thats right , my initial plan had just been to substring the name and decide which was most recent based on that but not sure how to specify which files name to substring

Comment: @wudzik: Looking at the OP's first question, I saw that he wants to process all files that start with a specific pattern (e.g. DOG*). user2546071: Please be more precise in describing what you want. You can't have more than one file with the same name in a directory, therefore your explanation is confusing.

Comment: StartsWith is case-sensitive. Did debug it and check is they are processed?

Comment: yes, since you can't have 2 files of exactly same name in a single directory, by using FileInfo.LastWriteTime you can sort out latest time of all the files and then get the file with latest date.

Comment: And with a little LINQ this becomes a one-liner: `return new DirectoryInfo(THE_PATH).GetFiles().OrderByDescending(x => x.LastWriteTimeUtc).FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get time of modification of file (most recent file) use

```
FileInfo.LastWriteTime and FileInfo.LastWriteTimeUTC
```

Then you can take file with latest date.

Comment: Brilliant , right I've got that working "ish" but now i think maybe my initial thoughts on the problem where wrong. I have the directory (still with two files of the same name) but when I check my breakpoint I can see that the sort is working and its picking the most recent one however its still crashing because their are two files of the same name , is it possible to specify within my sorting function to delete the file which is not the most recent ?  sorry about this but I'm a c# noob (clearly) :P

Comment: @user2546071 - "two files of the same name" - that's still impossible. Please elaborate on what you're trying to say with that and please be as precise as possible about it.

Comment: one file may be called dog1234 and the other might be called dog1243. my first thought would be just compare the names but based on how the system is meant to run (using the keywords) this is not an option. Using the above answer solved the problem of picking the most recent file , my issue now is removing the non most recent file

Comment: NVM !! I managed to get it working , very hacky (just minus'd the filecount) but still works

Comment: By "remove" you mean delete the file? So basically `foreach file in directory: if file.FileName != nameOfMostRecentFile: file.Delete`.