# How to take a file name contains todays date in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an FTP location contains files created daily basis.I need to take the files created today.Files are like

```
test-tester2016060720001.xml.zip    /todays one
test-tester2016060620001.xml.zip
test-tester2016060520001.xml.zip
```

I need a logic in c# to get file name contains todays date ie `test-tester2016060720001.xml.zip` for today

Comment: Better to check the created date instead for parsing the name?

Comment: but this is a FTP location ,last modified date is there as created date,but how to check it?

Comment: These links have enough material to solve your issue, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765789/getting-files-by-creation-date-in-net>, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185378/how-do-i-get-modified-date-from-file-in-c>, <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23243336/how-to-get-file-created-date-and-modified-date>

Answer (score 5):

This might do what you need.

```
var filePattern = String.Format("test-tester{0}*.xml.zip", DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Test");
FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles(filePattern);

foreach(FileInfo file in Files )
{
  //Do what you want with the file
}
```