# Filter DirectoryInfo files by date in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, date, datagrid, directoryinfo

I am populating a datagrid control using files in a specified path (DirectoryInfo).
I would like to filter the files based on a user specified date range (start date & end date).

While search S/O, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles) post, but I am getting an error on DateComparer (**"'DateComparer' is a type and cannot be used as an expression."**)

Any other suggestions on how to filter by date?

Here is my code:

```
        Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(strDirectoryPath)
        Dim dStartDate As DateTime = "03/01/2011"
        Dim dEndDate As DateTime = "6/30/2011"
        Dim Files As FileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles().Where(Function(Files) Files.CreationTime >= (dStartDate) AndAlso Files.CreationTime <= dEndDate)

            datagrid.DataSource = Files
            datagrid.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime your_start_date = new DateTime(2011,1,1);
DateTime your_end_date = new DateTime(2011,10,1);
FileInfo [] files = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\").GetFiles().Where(x=>x.CreationTime>=(your_start_date) && x.CreationTime<=(your_end_date)).ToArray();

foreach(var item in files)
{
 Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```

On my test case prints out:

```
copy_one.jpg
copy_one_one.jpg
copy_one_one_one.jpg
hiberfil.sys
one.jpg
pagefile.sys
PcapDotNet.snk
```

**UPDATE (VB version):**

```
Dim your_start_date As New DateTime(2011, 1, 1)
Dim your_end_date As New DateTime(2011, 10, 1)
Dim files As FileInfo() = New DirectoryInfo("c:\").GetFiles().Where(Function(x) x.CreationTime >= (your_start_date) AndAlso x.CreationTime <= (your_end_date)).ToArray()

For Each item As FileInfo In files
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name)
Next
```

Comment: what is "x" supposed to be in your last line?

Comment: The `GetFiles()` method returns an array of type `FileInfo`; therefore in `Where(x...)`, `x` is a `FileInfo` object.

Comment: so it would be like "files=>files.CreationTime" ?

Comment: @Troy You are trying to get files within a specified date range, correct? If so, then yes, files=>files.CreationTime>= somedate andalso files.CreationTime<=someotherdate.

Comment: yes, trying to get files within a date range. Check out my original post, I added my code.

Comment: Getting an error at dirInfo.GetFiles().Where..... "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Where' can be called with these arguments"

Comment: @Troy, I tested my VB.NET version (see update on my answer) and it works fine. What version of the .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: @Troy Should work just fine. Copy and paste my version of the code adapted to your needs.

Comment: @Troy this is asp.net; it's not enough to set DataSource=files you also need to do dgInvoiceList.DataBind() right after that.

Comment: I am doing the databind, but no records are showing (updated original post)

Comment: @Troy That can only mean one of 3 things: You did not set AutoGenerateColumns =true to your gridview; there are no files within the date range specified or you don't have permissions to the path specified in `strDirectoryPath` and an exception is being thrown but you are eating it. Are you using Cassini or IIS to debug your app?

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns is set to True; Files do exist that should show up in that date range; I have a try catch block with a Msgbox(ex.tostring()) so I should see any exceptions; I have permissions (since I got records before I started to filter by date)

Comment: This is my local machine, so I am using VS 2008 to dev and debug

Comment: @Troy What do you mean by `MSgBox`? `MsgBox` is for `Winforms`, is it not? It will never display anything on a Web app. You tagged the question with `asp.net`

Comment: yes, I am using asp.net. The MsgBox seems to work on my machine (I guess since its a local web server). I have a breakpoint at "Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(strDirectoryPath) " so when I walk thru the code, there are no expections.

Comment: nevermind... my bad. My code had "CreationTime" and the datagrid was using "LastWriteTime". It works now. Thanks very much for your help !!

Comment: dude... you went out of your way to see me thru to the end... I appreciate that. Thanks again.