# Displaying selective columns in an asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, gridview, directoryinfo

This is a follow up to my previous question:  [Filter DirectoryInfo files by date in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704881/filter-directoryinfo-files-by-date-in-asp-net)

I have a gridview that is populating data from DirectoryInfo.
However, I only want to display certain columns, and customize the column names and the hyperlink value in the row.

My code is:

```
Dim files As FileInfo() = New DirectoryInfo(strDirectoryPath).GetFiles().Where(Function(x) x.LastWriteTime >= (dtStartDate) AndAlso x.LastWriteTime <= (dtEndDate)).ToArray()  

For Each col In Gridview.Columns
If InStr(1, ",name,Extension,LastWriteTime,", "," & col.ColumnName.ToString.Trim & ",") > 0 Then
                        Dim hfield As HyperLinkField = New HyperLinkField()
                        hfield.DataTextField = col.ColumnName
                        hfield.HeaderText = "<table><tr><td align=""center"">" & col.ColumnName & "</td></tr></table>"
                        gvInvoiceList.Columns.Add(hfield)
                        i += 1
                    End If
Next
```

**Question:**
How can I loop through the columns, to display only "name", "extension" and LastWriteTime?

Answer (score 0):

Just [customize the GridView columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx), listing only the ones you want. Though, if you *really* want something like a nested table in your column name header, you'll need to step up to a Repeater or ListView instead.