# File Sorting using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, sorting, file-io, filesort

how to sort the files in the directory ?

i'll have more than 500 no of files in the below format.

```
prod_orders_XXX_<TimeStamp>.dat 

XXX         =  symbol of the product and the length may varies between 3-6.
<TimeStamp> =  date and time
```

Multiple files for the same XXX are possible with different time stamps.

Here are some examples:

```
prod_orders_abc_20122001083000.dat 
prod_orders_abc_20122001083111.dat 
prod_orders_xyz_20122001093157.dat 
prod_orders_xyz_20122001083000.dat 
prod_orders_abc_20122001163139.dat 
prod_orders_abc_20122001093137.dat
```

Comment: Check this link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles

Comment: Please show an example FileName. How do you want to sort, filename ascending, creationtime descending?

Comment: prod_orders_abc_201220010830000.dat prod_orders_abc_201220010831000.dat prod_orders_xyz_201220010931670.dat prod_orders_xyz_201220010830000.dat prod_orders_abc_201220011631000.dat prod_orders_abc_201220010931670.dat

Comment: Need to sort by creationtime decending..

Comment: With creation-time you don't mean the file-creation time but your timestamp in the filename, do you? See my edited answer

Comment: The timestamp in the file as showed will order the first of february right after the first of january and before the second of january. Is this what you want?

Comment: You should tell us how you are converting the timestamp to that string, because it looks odd. `yyyyddmmhhmmssm` So either there is no second or there is only a tenth of a second as millis. Apart from that, `201220010931670` would result in 67 seconds what is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide the correct sample files and requirement right off the next time ;)

Here is what you need:

```
Dim fileList = (From file In New IO.DirectoryInfo(directoryPath).GetFiles()
          Where file.Name.IndexOf("prod_orders_") > -1
          Let dateIndex = file.Name.LastIndexOf("_") + 1
          Let dateIndexEnd = file.Name.LastIndexOf(".")
          Let datePart = file.Name.Substring(dateIndex, dateIndexEnd - dateIndex)
          Where datePart.Length = 14 AndAlso ULong.TryParse(datePart, 0)
          Let year = Int32.Parse(datePart.Substring(0, 4))
          Let day = Int32.Parse(datePart.Substring(4, 2))
          Let month = Int32.Parse(datePart.Substring(6, 2))
          Let hour = Int32.Parse(datePart.Substring(8, 2))
          Let minute = Int32.Parse(datePart.Substring(10, 2))
          Let second = Int32.Parse(datePart.Substring(12, 2))
          Let timestamp = New Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)
          Order By timestamp Descending
          Select file).ToList()
```

Comment: Hello Tim, i just reedited my post. Sorry for the Inconvenience.

Comment: @Santhosh: Edited my answer, please provide the correct requirement and samples next time ;)