# FileSort in visual basic based TimeStamp mentioned in the file names

Tags: vb.net, sorting, filesort

how to sort the files in the directory based on the part of the file name?

File format:
`prod_orders_XXX_<TimeStamp>.datXXX = symbol of the product and the length may varies.

<TimeStamp> = date and time`

Multiple files for the same XXX are possible with different time stamps.

Here are some examples:

```
prod_orders_abc_20122001083000.dat
prod_orders_abc_20122007083111.dat
prod_orders_xyz_20122003093157.dat
prod_orders_xyz_20122001083000.dat
prod_orders_abc_20122001163139.dat
prod_orders_abc_20122002093137.dat
prod_orders_xyz_20122001183000.dat
prod_orders_abc_20122001163139.dat
prod_orders_abc_20122001093137.dat
```

I need to sort the files based on the time stamp mentioned as part of file name.

Comment: I tried Hashtable by taking timestamp as key and the filename(prod_orders_xyz) as value and then will sort the hashkey by assigning them into arraylist. but when two files with same timestamp and diff filenames arrives i need to append them with the existing value and manipulate it again to store all the values into arraylist.Is there any efficient way to sort these files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what your looking for.  You'll need to make sure the Date format is correct (I guessed it..) and add some extra validation.

```
    Dim filename As String = "prod_orders_abc_20122001083000.dat"

    filename = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename.Split("_").Last)

    'yyyyddMMhhmmss
    '20122001083000
    Dim fileDate As Date

    If Date.TryParseExact(filename, "yyyyddMMhhmmss", Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, fileDate) Then
        Debug.WriteLine(fileDate)
    Else
        Debug.WriteLine("unable to get date")
    End If
```

Edit, sorry just noticed you wanted to sort them all...

```
    Sub main()

    Dim filenames() As String =
        {"prod_orders_abc_20122001083000.dat",
         "prod_orders_abc_20122007083111.dat",
         "prod_orders_xyz_20122003093157.dat",
         "prod_orders_xyz_20122001083000.dat",
         "prod_orders_abc_20122001163139.dat",
         "prod_orders_abc_20122002093137.dat",
         "prod_orders_xyz_20122001183000.dat",
         "prod_orders_abc_20122001163139.dat",
         "prod_orders_abc_20122001093137.dat"}


    Dim SortedFileNames As List(Of String) =
        filenames.OrderBy(Function(fileName) GetDateFromFileName(fileName)).ToList


End Sub

Private Function GetDateFromFileName(fileName As String) As Date

    fileName = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName.Split("_").Last)

    'yyyyddMMhhmmss
    '20122001083000
    Dim fileDate As Date

    If Date.TryParseExact(fileName, "yyyyddMMhhmmss", Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, fileDate) Then
        Return fileDate
    Else
        Return Date.MinValue
    End If

End Function
```

End Module

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not providing a VB answer, but it can't be hard to convert it to VB.NET
The following code will stort the array by the timestamp.

```
string[] fileNames = 
{ "prod_orders_abc_20122001083000.dat",
  "prod_orders_abc_20122007083111.dat",
  "prod_orders_xyz_20122003093157.dat",
  "prod_orders_xyz_20122001083000.dat",
  "prod_orders_abc_20122001163139.dat",
  "prod_orders_abc_20122002093137.dat",
  "prod_orders_xyz_20122001183000.dat",
  "prod_orders_abc_20122001163139.dat",
  "prod_orders_abc_20122001093137.dat" 
};

var result = fileNames.OrderBy(s => s.Substring(s.Length - 12,4)).ToArray();
```

UPDATE: 
VB version of the same code.

```
Dim fileNames As String() = {"prod_orders_abc_20122001083000.dat", "prod_orders_abc_20122007083111.dat", "prod_orders_xyz_20122003093157.dat", "prod_orders_xyz_20122001083000.dat", "prod_orders_abc_20122001163139.dat", "prod_orders_abc_20122002093137.dat", _
    "prod_orders_xyz_20122001183000.dat", "prod_orders_abc_20122001163139.dat", "prod_orders_abc_20122001093137.dat"}

Dim result = fileNames.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Substring(s.Length - 12, 4)).ToArray()
```