# How to put newer files at top of datagrid?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

Here is a script for displaying name of files (for download) in data grid table. Is it  possible that to show the latest created file in top row?. Please help.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<script language="VB" runat="server">
Sub Page_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
If Not Page.IsPostBack then
        Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo("D:\SeverUpload\Safety")

        articleList.DataSource = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*")
  articleList.DataBind()
End If
 End Sub

 Sub articleList_ItemDataBound(sender as Object, e as DataGridItemEventArgs)
' First, make sure we're NOT dealing with a Header or Footer row
If e.Item.ItemType <> ListItemType.Header AND _
     e.Item.ItemType <> ListItemType.Footer then
  'Now, reference the Button control that the Delete ButtonColumn 
  'has been rendered to
  Dim deleteButton as Button = e.Item.Cells(0).Controls(0)

  'We can now add the onclick event handler
  deleteButton.Attributes("onclick") = "javascript:return " & _
             "confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the file " & _
             DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Name") & "?')"    
   End If
  End Sub


 Sub articleList_DeleteFile(sender as Object, e as DataGridCommandEventArgs)
'First, get the filename to delete
Dim fileName as String = articleList.DataKeys(e.Item.ItemIndex)

'lblMessage.Text = "You opted to delete the file " & _
    'fileName & ".<br />" & _
    '"This file could be deleted by calling: " & _
    '"<code>File.Delete(FileName)</code><p>"

'You would want to rebind the Directory's files to the DataGrid after
'deleting the file...
End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: Check out this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles) whose winning answer explains the use of System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos()

Answer (score 0):

Where is the data being loaded in at? It's possibly to just add a `ORDER BY DATETIME DESC` when querying the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below in the page load.

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack then
        Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo("D:\SeverUpload\Safety")
        Dim files As FileSystemInfo() = dirInfo.GetFileSystemInfos("*.*")
        Dim orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(Function(f) f.CreationTime)

        articleList.DataSource = orderedFiles
  articleList.DataBind()
End If
```

Comment: Sir, with using this error appears as below: Exception Details: System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.

Source Error: 

Line 48:             articleList.DataBind()

Comment: <asp:DataGrid runat="server" id="articleList" Font-Name="Verdana"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False" AlternatingItemStyle-BackColor="#eeeeee"
      HeaderStyle-BackColor="Navy" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
      HeaderStyle-Font-Size="15pt" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="True"
      DataKeyField="FullName"
      OnItemDataBound="articleList_ItemDataBound"
      OnDeleteCommand="articleList_DeleteFile" Font-Bold="False" 
      Font-Italic="False" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Overline="False" 
      Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Center">