# getting directory list in creation date order in .Net 3.0

Tags: c#, .net

I need to get list of sub-directories from a directory ordered by CreationDate in **.Net 3.0**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/52842/16391 gives you a way to order the Files in a directory, you would just need to substitute the GetDirectory for GetFile and DirectoryInfo for FileInfo

Answer (score 19):

You should be able to use the [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2fzb02) class for this (requires .NET 4):

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(theFolder);
var directories = di.EnumerateDirectories()
                    .OrderBy(d => d.CreationTime)
                    .Select(d => d.Name)
                    .ToList();
```

In .NET 3.0, you could use [`DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx), then sort the array afterwards using the same logic.

Answer (score 4):

1) You can use  [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx)  to get a list of *paths* of all sub-directories.

2) One time got it convert the list of paths into the list of [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) objects.
   Every [DirectoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.aspx) contains [FileSystemInfo.CreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx) property.

3) So the last thing that remains is to order a list based on that property.