# Get sub directories list order by created date in ascending order

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, io

I want to get the sub directories list in ascending order on created date means the oldest directory should be first and so on.

> List subfolders = Directory.GetDirectories(source).ToList();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting directory list in creation date order in .Net 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009615/getting-directory-list-in-creation-date-order-in-net-3-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DirectoryInfo`. `DirectoryInfo` contains `FileSystemInfo.CreationTime` property.

```
var di = new DirectoryInfo(source);
var subfolders= di.EnumerateDirectories()
                  .OrderBy(d => d.CreationTime)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58(v=vs.110).aspx) will be more suitable here, you can do like the following:

```
string source = "source Path here";
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(source);
var subfolders = dInfo.GetDirectories(source).OrderBy(x=>x.CreationTime).ToList();
```

Here the result of `dInfo.GetDirectories` will be of type `System.IO.DirectoryInfo[]` you can get Name,path or any related from each object of the `subfolders`