# C# Get latest directory in a path - with respect to the the name of directory

Tags: c#

i have a requirement to get the last created directory in a path with respect to its name, as an application i use created 2 directories during the runtime and i need to consider only one of them, which in order appears later. For e.g the app creates 2 folders with name: 60000c and b3c143 and i need the one with the name "b3c143". How can i acheive this? Thanks. I get the latest one using the code:

```
    string path = @"C:\temp";
        string mostRecentlyModified = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
           .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
           .OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastAccessTime)
           .First()
           .FullName;
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with that code ?

Comment: Keep track of them when you create them, after all you create them. Querying this after the fact seems like an extra degree of freedom, and just one more thing to go wrong

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i am not getting the the folder i require- thats with name b3c143 as the folder 60000c is created too with the same time and appears latest.

Comment: @MichaelRandall i can access only after the whole stuff is over :( so would like to know if its possible to filter in the linq itself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009615/getting-directory-list-in-creation-date-order-in-net-3-0

Comment: LastAccessTime is not CreationTime

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298725/multiple-order-by-in-linq

Comment: Try this => `.OrderByDescending(fi => fi.LastWriteTimeUtc).First().FullName;`

Comment: Or you could use => `fi.LastWriteTime` without UTC

Comment: No..it doesnt help..still gives the th eother folder

Comment: Is it possible to use .Contains() for filtering the directory with name?

Comment: So you want it by name or last created time?

Comment: @sina123, I added my answer below try it and let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your desired directory with its name by passing it to `.Where()` func and by its last write time.

```
string mostRecentlyModified = Directory.GetDirectories(path)
               .Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d))
               .Where(d => d.Name == "b3c143" && d.Exists) //.Where(d => d.Name.Trim().ToLower().Contains("b3c143".Trim().ToLower()) && d.Exists)
               .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTime)
               .First()
               .FullName;
```