# What's the behavior of get files when used to get files in folders? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, getfiles

I am writing a asp.net+c# code to get all files in a directory
I am using the following statements:

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/someFolder"));
```

my question is when executing this statement, what is the behavior of GetFiles here?
is there any criteria for storing the files in the array? I mean does executing this statement many times brings the files with the same order? does it get them ordered by date, name, ?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52842/sorting-directory-getfiles

Answer (score 0):

You can ordered the files list by name, size and date.
To sort by name,

```
var sorted = files.OrderBy(file => file);
```

To sort by size,

```
var sorted = files.OrderBy(file=> new FileInfo(file).Length);
```

To sort by date,

```
var sorted = files.OrderBy(file=> file.CreationTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

User this code:

```
var lst = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/someFolder")).GetFiles()
              .OrderBy(x => new { x.CreationTime, x.Name });
```

Use linq to order your list, then

```
string[] files = lst.Select(x => x.FullName).ToArray();
```